# How do I remove the iPhone/iOS white screen bounce when using the Cordova InAppBrowser?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm struggling with an issue which causes the Cordova-InAppBrowser to have a white screen bounce on every page, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved by changing line 191 of Plugins/CDVInAppBrowser.m within the Cordova project.

Replacing:

```
if (browserOptions.disallowoverscroll) {
    if ([self.inAppBrowserViewController.webView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]) {
        ((UIScrollView*)[self.inAppBrowserViewController.webView scrollView]).bounces = NO;
    } else {
        for (id subview in self.inAppBrowserViewController.webView.subviews) {
            if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
                ((UIScrollView*)subview).bounces = NO;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
    if ([self.inAppBrowserViewController.webView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]) {
        ((UIScrollView*)[self.inAppBrowserViewController.webView scrollView]).bounces = NO;
    } else {
        for (id subview in self.inAppBrowserViewController.webView.subviews) {
            if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
                ((UIScrollView*)subview).bounces = NO;
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope anyone struggling with this issue can solve it with this :)